# How to perform string replacement on a word document using command line (CLI)

Tags: php, vba, vbscript, ms-word, docx

I have a word document template that I need to do a find and replace on.
For example I need to replace `<address 1>` with `1 Test Street`.

I have tried doing this using a macro which I can run from command line but you don't seem to be able to pass in arguments and therefore cannot edit either the pattern you are searching for or the thing to replace it with.

I need to it using PHP ultimately so had been looking for something I can just call with an exec, I did find a library called PHPWord that looked very useful but the way it worked was to parse the .doc file into an xml file and this wasn't working properly resulting in words being split in half and therefore no good for a str_replace.

Finally I looked at using VBScript, I have no experience with this at all and could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Interop to access the Word document. 
You will have to use .NET for this, and you can create a console application.

Have a look at [Interop Class Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [this for an example](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/dotnet/soa/Easily-utilise-Microsoft-Word-functionality-in-your-NET-application/0,339028399,339198903,00.htm).

Comment: That works great thanks, the only trouble I am having now is calling the C# program I have made from my PHP page, I think it is some sort of permissions problem but can't work out what.

Answer (score 1):

To replace an existing string of text in a Word document by another one with PHP, and perserving all Word styles, is now quite simple if you use PHPDocX: [Replacing text in a Word document with PHP](http://www.phpdocx.com/archives/2291)

This procedure is rather more difficult to implement that it may seem because of the way Word (OOXML standard) breaks the paragraph contents into different runs of text. For example, a single word may be broken into different runs of text with tehir own markup if the original editor of the Word document has introduced some corrections or even if (s)he has hit the back key.

The searchAndReplace method of PHPDocX looks for a certain string of text, extracts its Word styles, and reconstruct the corresponding paragrah with the replacement text preserving all the original styles.

One may choose to search and replace the whole document, including headers, footers, footnotes, comments, etcetera, or if performance is important one may choose to specify a part. Nevertheless the method is rather fast and replacing a string of text in a one hundred page Word document may take a few hundredths of a second.

Answer (score -1):

I am not so familiar with php or VBScript

The task is easy in python ::

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    f = open(filename,'r')
    output = f.read().replace('<Address 1>','1 Test Street')
    f.close()
    f = open('filename','w')
    f.write(output)
    f.close()
```

Run the file on command line as $python thisfile.py filename

Comment: Thankyou for the reponse, I tried this out and firstly I got an unusable file and then I tried taking the 'filename' out of the quotes on the thrid line from the bottom and got a permission denied error

Comment: I just realised to put .docx extension in to read 'filename.docx' on the third line from the bottom but this just creates a corrupt file.

Comment: I dont use windows so much . Try running diff to see what I did wrong . Also there is one error in line 8 :: open(filename,'w')

Comment: Thanks for you help, though the code above only seems to work for txt files, I need to be able to search and replace in .docx and .doc files.

Comment: -1 for not actually reading the question. This obviously works for ascii files but not for docx files.